# Connection to xxxxx was not upgraded to websocket. Only on desktop, works fine on web

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket

I try to connect to a websocket in the following way

```
final channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(
  Uri.parse('wss://xxxxx'),
);
```

I build my app for web and for desktop (windows). On web this works fine, but on desktop it doesn't and gives the following error

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: WebSocketChannelException: WebSocketChannelException: WebSocketException: Connection to 'https://xxxxx#' was not upgraded to websocket
#0      new IOWebSocketChannel._withoutSocket.<anonymous closure> (package:web_socket_channel/io.dart:98:24)
#1      Stream.handleError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream.dart:929:16)
#2      _HandleErrorStream._handleError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:269:17)
#3      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:157:13)
#4      _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1415:47)
#5      _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1307:19)
#6      _CustomZone.runBinaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1217:7)
#7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError.sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:358:15)
```

Now I understand there's different implementations between the two because one uses `dart:html` and the other `dart:io`. But I don't understand why it doesn't work on desktop, (and works fine on web).

Now I found many people having the same error, for example:

[Flutter Socket io Error on WebSocketException: Connection to was not upgraded to websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64125735/flutter-socket-io-error-on-websocketexception-connection-to-was-not-upgraded-to)

And there and other places the most common error seems to be server side related. But this doesn't explain why it works fine on web for me.

More importantly, I was finally able to make a workaround that does work on desktop like this (inspired by [Dart upgrade client Socket to WebSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53721745/dart-upgrade-client-socket-to-websocket)):

```
Random r = new Random();
String key = base64.encode(List<int>.generate(8, (_) => r.nextInt(255)));

HttpClient client = HttpClient();
HttpClientRequest request = await client.getUrl(Uri.parse('https://xxxxx'));
request.headers.add('connection', 'Upgrade');
request.headers.add('upgrade', 'websocket');
request.headers.add('Sec-WebSocket-Version', '13');
request.headers.add('Sec-WebSocket-Key', key);
HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();

Socket socket = await response.detachSocket();

WebSocket ws = WebSocket.fromUpgradedSocket(socket, serverSide: false);
ws.listen((event) {
  print(event);
});
```

Why does this workaround work fine and the "normal" way doesn't? Is there some important difference between the two ways?